# Enable shared libraries

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, fedora

On my new linux distro(Fedora) if I try to compile something that I have written with glfw I get the following error:

```
:-1: error: note: 'XF86VidModeQueryExtension' is defined in DSO /lib64/libXxf86vm.so.1 so try adding it to the linker command line
```

I can fix this by adding -lXxf86vm but I never had to include this in my previous linux distros. Now I have to add 6 lib names.

What is going on? it seems that my compiler refuses .so libs? I researched this a bit and it seems that I have to recompile my gcc with --enable-shared.

Is this true?

Here is my log from gcc:

```
    20:32:44: Running steps for project sgl...
20:32:44: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
20:32:44: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -std=c++11 -g -Wall -W -fPIE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -I../../Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I../kantaki-sgl -Ishaders -I. -o camera.o ../kantaki-sgl/camera.cpp
../kantaki-sgl/camera.cpp:3:6: warning: unused parameter 'pos' [-Wunused-parameter]
../kantaki-sgl/camera.cpp:7:6: warning: unused parameter 'ori' [-Wunused-parameter]
../kantaki-sgl/camera.cpp:14:6: warning: unused parameter 'window' [-Wunused-parameter]
../kantaki-sgl/camera.cpp:14:6: warning: unused parameter 'action' [-Wunused-parameter]
g++ -m64 -Wl,-rpath,/home/maik/Qt5.0.2/5.0.2/gcc_64 -o sgl main.o filereader.o shader.o camera.o   -lGL -lglfw3 -lglimgD -lglloadD 
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libglfw3.a(x11_clipboard.c.o): undefined reference to symbol 'XConvertSelection'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'XConvertSelection' is defined in DSO /lib64/libX11.so.6 so try adding it to the linker command line
/lib64/libX11.so.6: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [sgl] Error 1
20:32:45: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project sgl (kit: Desktop)
When executing step 'Make'
```

Edit I also compiled it with clang -> same result.

Comment: which distro do you use?

Comment: I am using fedora now.

Comment: did you run `ldconfig` ? Did you compile the library yourself ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes I have run ldconfig, even ldconfig -v and the libs are in there. I also run ldconfig -p and it outputs `libXxf86vm.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libXxf86vm.so.1` which seems correct right?

Comment: @n.m. I am not using a self compiled gcc, it came with fedora. I also tried to compile it with clang. -> same result. I added the gcc log in my post. I should also add that I need to add the following libs in order for my source code to compile `LIBS += -lXi
LIBS += -lX11
LIBS += -lXxf86vm
LIBS += -lpthread
LIBS += -lrt
LIBS += -lXrandr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a change in the DSO Linking strategy of Fedora, take a look at the [official documentation](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/UnderstandingDSOLinkChange).

Comment: Wow! That's one long overdue change. Hope other distros will follow.

Comment: So this basically means that I have to explicitly link every shared library ?